# testing using karma failed : Module app is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've included 3 files in my karma config : 1. angular.js, angular-mock.js, and login.spec.js

this is my login.spec.js:

```
describe("Hello World example", function() {

  beforeEach(module("app"));

  var loginCtrl,
  scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    loginCtrl = $controller('loginCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('says hello world!', function () {
    expect(scope.hello).toEqual("Hello");
  });

  });
```

so my login.js (controller) look like this

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    $scope.hello = 'hello';
  });
```

but I got `Module 'app' is not available!`

Comment: You have a beforeEach() including the app module. Are you importing it?

Comment: @rrd I don't know. I'm confused now, I tried   `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));`
it doesn't work too.

Comment: I would try playing around with the order in which `angular-mocks.js` is loaded. I'd recommend loading it after your main files but before your spec files.

Take a look at this setup

https://github.com/divyanthj/hello-world-angular/blob/master/helloWorld.conf.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you creating the app module anywere. You should include the app.js and all the sources your tests need to your karma.json as well.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this line to the top of your login.js file:

This declares the module:

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

This gets an instance of the module(as you are doing):

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    $scope.hello = 'hello';
  });
```

Here is a working Plunkr that is very similar:
http://embed.plnkr.co/O1otV47VxsIL5krAdUW0/preview

You also mentioned that you had added 3 files to the karma config and didn't mention the login.js.  That will also need to be added.